# "You must provide card details, token or paymentMethodId " error when calling confirmPayment function in stripe

Tags: react-native, expo, stripe-payments

I am using stripe in expo app, when calling confirmPayment method it gives error "You must provide card details, token or paymentMethodId " , here is my code

```
const handlePayPress = async () => {
    //1.Gather the customer's billing information (e.g., email)
    if (!cardDetails?.complete || !email) {
      Alert.alert("Please enter Complete card details and Email");
      return;
    }
    const billingDetails = {
      email: email,
    };
    //2.Fetch the intent client secret from the backend
    try {
      const { clientSecret, error } = await fetchPaymentIntentClientSecret();
      //2. confirm the payment
      if (error) {
        console.log("Unable to process payment");
      } else {
        const { paymentIntent, error } = await confirmPayment(clientSecret, {
          type: "Card",
          billingDetails: billingDetails,
        });
        if (error) {
          alert(`Payment Confirmation Error ${error.message}`);
        } else if (paymentIntent) {
          alert("Payment Successful");
          console.log("Payment successful ", paymentIntent);
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
    //3.Confirm the payment with the card details
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to integrate either the [Payment Sheet](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native&ui=payment-sheet#integrate-payment-sheet) or the [`CardField`](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native&ui=custom#react-native-create-checkout-page) to collect the payment details for the payment. Unlike the web/Stripe.js versions of this, the reference is not needed explicitly during the [confirm call](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements#web-submit-payment), but you do still need to have them in your app.